# How do I set up a MAC to use Selenium with Watir Webdriver and Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir-webdriver

Need help converting from a Windows to MAC environment.  I'm on OSX 10.9.5 and need to develop automated testing using Selenium, Ruby, and Watir Webdriver.  I'm not well versed in the MAC nature of things, so help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you listed specific questions, this is a rather broad topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote detailed instructions a while ago: https://leanpub.com/watirbook/read#leanpub-auto-mac-os-x-109

Comment: Installed everything successfully.  Can you recommend an editor that can be used to manage *.rb files?

Comment: A few that I have used: http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/ http://www.sublimetext.com/3 https://atom.io/

Comment: I'm missing watir-webdriver

Comment: Ok. Why don't you install it?

Comment: I don't know how.  Sorry, again, I'm new to MAC so I'm not even sure what I'm reading when I go to the download site.

Comment: From Terminal I tried "gem install watir-webdriver" and get this: 
NameError: undefined local variable or method `watir' for main:Object

Comment: Follow these instructions, but replace `selenium-webdriver` with `watir-webdriver` https://leanpub.com/watirbook/read#leanpub-auto-selenium-webdriver-1

Comment: Zelijko, tried again this evening on my MAC and the link worked fine.  I ran the command and it appears everything installed correctly.  Thank you again, for your help!

Comment: Well, on attempting to run my *.rb file using TextMate on the MAC, I get this error:  "cannot load such file watir web driver".

Comment: I ran gem local and the first line indicates this: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/magic-file.rb:7:in `initialize': No such file or directory - sudo (Errno::ENOENT)

Comment: BTW, I installed watir webdriver to the Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems directory.  I noticed all other gems are in that directory in folders; however watir-webdriver-06.11.gem is not.  Does this matter?

Comment: Please edit the question and put all relevant information there, or ask a new question. It is hard for me to see what is going on from you comments.

Comment: Zeijko ... everything is working thanks to your help and some perseverance.